# Prove that $\{a \in (0,1) \mid |f(a)-L(a)|>1\}$ is finite

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function continuous at the points $0$ and $1$ and such that the limits $L(a)=\lim _{x \to a} f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$ exist for every $a \in (0,1)$. Prove that the set $\{a \in (0,1) \mid |f(a)-L(a)|>1\}$ must be finite.

I have no clue where to start with this problem.

Comment: Note proper notation for sets in MathJax or LaTeX: $$ \mathscr S = \{a,b,c,d\} $$ $$ \mathscr T = \left\{ \frac 1 2, \frac 3 2 \right\} $$ Also note the use of \mid, as in my edit to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the set $$A = \{a\mid a\in(0, 1), |f(a) - L(a)| > 1\}$$ is bounded. If it is infinite then by Bolzano Weierstrass theorem there is an accumulation point $c$ of $A$ in $[0, 1]$.

Note that the function $L$ is continuous on $[0, 1]$ (try to prove yourself). Consider the sequence of point $x_{n} \in A$ such that $x_{n} \to c$. Then we have $$|f(x_{n}) - L(x_{n})| > 1$$ for all $n$. Letting $n \to \infty$ we see that $|L(c) - L(c)| \geq 1$ which is a contradiction.

Note that the continuity of $f$ at end points is not needed. What is needed is that $f$ has one sided limits at the endpoints $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Show that this subset of $ [0, 1] $ is closed (thus compact) and discrete in the subspace topology.